# Polar image plot

Tags: plotting

I would like to perform the polar plot of an electron microscope [contrast transfer function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrast_transfer_function), into a black and white image.

I have used the equation

```
t = -Sin[π/2 #^4 + π #^2 ] &;

Plot[t[x], {x, 0, 5}]
```

to generate the sample function.

[image]

However, I was unable to convert this image into the contrast transfer function plot.

In short, what function would convert the plot

[image]

into the image

[image]

Comment: Take a look at `DensityPlot`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = 1.5;
DensityPlot[t[Norm[{x, y}]], {x, -a, a}, {y, -a, a}, PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But beware of the tuning parameters:

```
a = 5;
DensityPlot[t[Norm[{x, y}]], {x, -a, a}, {y, -a, a}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks! I tried density plot first, but gave up after it gave me the ridiculous pattern.

Comment: @MarchHo Somehow I guessed that. That's why I included the last plot :)